# Translating address label issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, translate

This is my string, which I would love to translate:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Street Address %s', $_i)) ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street<?php echo $_i ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
```

These are my tries from my theme csv file:

```
"Mage_Customer::Street Address 1","RUE"
"Mage_Customer::Street Address 2","Numéro"
"Mage_Customer::Street Address 3","Boîte"
"Mage_Customer::Street Address 4","Addition"
"Mage_Checkout::Street Address","RUE"
"Mage_Checkout::Street Address 2","Numéro"
"Mage_Checkout::Street Address 3","Boîte"
"Mage_Checkout::Street Address 4","Addition"
"Street Address","RUE"
"Street Address 2","Numéro"
"Street Address 3","Boîte"
"Street Address 4","Addition"


"Street Address %s","RUE"
```

Interesting about using the last one. It translates me all of the address labels into `RUE`. Inline translations were not used. The `core_translate` table is empty. Any other idea how should I translate my strings ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
"Street Address 1","RUE"
"Street Address 2","Numéro"
"Street Address 3","Boîte"
"Street Address 4","Addition"
```

You'd update your code to this then:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Street Address ' . $_i); ?>
```

Comment: I have now `RUE 1`  and `RUE2` and `RUE4`  . I would like to have `RUE`, `Numéro`, `Boîte `and `Addition`

Comment: I've updated the answer ;)

Comment: using your code it display the address label's values , which are custom . How could that be translatable ? :)

Comment: For me is all about the `placeholder` and the `title` not  the `value` of the inputs

Comment: I've misunderstood what you want, sorry... I've edited my answer again ;)

Comment: I know . I tried this version before and it  works, but I thought that this can be solved only from CSV translations without changing the phtml files.